# Django rest framework, translate model with django-hvad

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-hvad

I have model `Product`:

```
class Product(TranslatableModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    translations = TranslatedFields(
        description=models.TextField(),
    )
```

and in administration on product detail I have tabs with languages. For example tabs EN, CZ, each includes `disctiption`. So PUT request looks like:

```
{
    'product': '1',
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'Name', 
    'translations': {
        'cz': {'desctiption': 'Description cz'},
        'en': {'desctiption': 'Description en'}
    }
}
```

I founded in [django-hvad TranslationsMixin](http://django-hvad.readthedocs.io/en/latest/public/restframework.html#translationsmixin) that allows me to do that request.

in serializers I have:

```
class ProductTranslationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        exclude = ['description']


class ProductSerializer(TranslationsMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        translations_serializer = ProductTranslationSerializer
        fields = (
            'name', 
            'description',
        )
```

Question is how will looks ModelViewSet for this request? Can I choose language like 'language_code=en', filter that query and get something like:

```
[
    {
        id: 1
        name: "name"
        descritpion: "descritpion"
    },
    ....
]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the most likely way i achieve is:

models.py

```
class Product(TranslatableModel):
    category = models.ForeignKey('product.ProductCategory',
                                 related_name='product_category',
                                 null=True,
                                 on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                 verbose_name=u'category')
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to=product_cover,
                              null=True,
                              verbose_name=u'cover')
    translations = TranslatedFields(
        title=models.CharField(max_length=100,
                               null=True,
                               verbose_name=u'title'),
        summary=models.TextField(null=True,
                                 verbose_name=u'summary'),
        model=models.CharField(max_length=255,
                               null=True,
                               blank=True,
                               verbose_name=u'model'),
        price=models.DecimalField(default=0.00,
                                  max_digits=10,
                                  decimal_places=2,
                                  blank=True,
                                  validators=[MinValueValidator(0)],
                                  verbose_name=u'price'),
        content=models.TextField(verbose_name=u'content'),
        publish_time=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now,
                                          verbose_name=u'发布publish_time')

    )
    view_times = models.IntegerField(default=0,
                                     verbose_name=u'view_times ')
```

views.py

```
class ProductViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProductListSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        if 'language_code' in self.request.GET:
            language_code = self.request.GET.get('language_code')
            queryset = Product.objects.language(language_code).order_by('-id')
        else:
            queryset = Product.objects.language().order_by('-id')
        return queryset
```

serializers.py

```
class ProductCategorySerializer(TranslatableModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductCategory
        fields = '__all__'



class ProductListSerializer(TranslatableModelSerializer):
    category = ProductCategorySerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        exclude = ['is_abandon', 'content', ]
```

urls.py

```
   from rest_framework import routers
   router = routers.DefaultRouter()
   router.register(r'product', ProductViewSet, base_name='api-product')
   ...
```

result:
http://192.168.1.108/api/product/?language_code=zh-hans you get:

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "page_num": 1,
    "page_no": 1,
    "next": "",
    "previous": "",
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "category": {
                "id": 2,
                "create_time": "2017-08-10 16:49:41",
                "update_time": "2017-08-18 08:56:02",
                "name": "测试",
                "language_code": "zh-hans"
            },
            "create_time": "2017-08-18 08:53:46",
            "update_time": "2017-08-18 08:56:28",
            "cover": "http://192.168.1.108/media/product/20170818-085346-518_59.jpg",
            "view_times": 0,
            "title": "标题",
            "summary": "简介",
            "model": null,
            "price": "90.00",
            "publish_time": "2017-08-18 08:53:00",
            "language_code": "zh-hans"
        }
    ]
}
```

http://192.168.1.108/api/product/?language_code=en you get:

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "page_num": 1,
    "page_no": 1,
    "next": "",
    "previous": "",
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "category": {
                "id": 2,
                "create_time": "2017-08-10 16:49:41",
                "update_time": "2017-08-18 08:56:02",
                "name": "测试",
                "language_code": "zh-hans"
            },
            "create_time": "2017-08-18 08:53:46",
            "update_time": "2017-08-18 09:00:23",
            "cover": "http://192.168.1.108/media/product/20170818-085346-518_59.jpg",
            "view_times": 0,
            "title": "title",
            "summary": "summary",
            "model": "model",
            "price": "91.00",
            "publish_time": "2017-08-18 08:56:04",
            "language_code": "en"
        }
    ]
}
```

this way fk will not change language,if you want fk change language too,use:
urls.py

```
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    '''
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
    prefix_default_language=False,
)
```

change language by

```
 http://192.168.1.108/zh-hans/api/product/
```

to

```
 http://192.168.1.108/en/api/product/
```

your will get:

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "page_num": 1,
    "page_no": 1,
    "next": "",
    "previous": "",
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "category": {
                "id": 2,
                "create_time": "2017-08-10 16:49:41",
                "update_time": "2017-08-18 08:56:02",
                "name": "test",
                "language_code": "en"
            },
            "create_time": "2017-08-18 08:53:46",
            "update_time": "2017-08-18 09:00:23",
            "cover": "http://192.168.1.108/media/product/20170818-085346-518_59.jpg",
            "view_times": 0,
            "title": "title",
            "summary": "summary",
            "model": "model",
            "price": "91.00",
            "publish_time": "2017-08-18 08:56:04",
            "language_code": "en"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for usefull infromation!

Answer (score 0):

Answer from owner of django-hvad github repo @spectras:

If I understand well, you want to use a different serialized form for the collection endpoint and the item endpoint. That is, GET-1, PUT, POST would use the translations mixin, while GET-many would not.
You need two have two different serializers for this:

1. The one you created
2. another one that would be, for instance,
   `class ProductItemSerializer(TranslatableModelSerializer):` ...

another one that would be, for instance,
class ProductItemSerializer(TranslatableModelSerializer): ...
Given that, you can add to your ModelViewSet a method that dynamically chooses the serializer class depending on request type:

```
class SomeModelViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    # serializer_class = not needed, we use the method instead
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'list':
            return ProductItemSerializer
        return ProductSerializer
```

An alternate method, perhaps easier to use on the Javascript side, would be to make 2 viewsets for the Product model, a read-write one being translation aware (using ProductSerializer) and a read-only one not translation aware, using (ProductItemSerializer).

In the same vein, I usually only have translation-unaware serializers and add a /api/product/details/ endpoint that is translation-aware. This way, I only have to handle the complexity of a dict object when going into edit/detailed mode on the client side.